# Custom [Compare()] attribute to compare two properties of a class via data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, data-annotations

I'm wanting to roll a couple of different customer `[Compare()]` attributes to use in an MVC4 application.  The part I'm having issues with is the `public string OtherPropertyDisplayName { get; internal set; }` that Microsoft implements.  How are they getting the information to populate this field?  I'm assuming it's through reflection...and my reflection foo is weak so does anyone have pointers for this?

I have made my own custom attributes before, but never one that needed knowledge of the "other" field.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it: [Property Matching With Data Annotations](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/09/property-matching-with-data-annotations/)

Essentially, they define `Match` attribute rather than `Compare`, but this is only a different word for the same thing, Just use that example to see what they do and do the same in your case. It isn't hard at all.

Good luck & please let me know if that was of help.

Comment: Was it of any help please?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test yet.  As soon as I have time to read through it and use it I'll be sure to up vote/accept.  Also just an FYI on the edit of the title.  It's generally recommended to not put the technology in the title (unless it's needed to ask the question) since we have tags.  The "ASP.NET MVC - " should be gathered from the relevant tags that you added.

Comment: Looks like @DisplayName showed the OP how to do exactly what was asked - why isn't it marked as the answer?